# How to count DIV element and insert break line

Tags: jquery

I would like to insert a break line after the second or third DIV element.
Any ideas how to use Jquery  ot do that?
Thanks

```
<div class="column"> 
    <h3>Web Development</h3> 
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/">Dynamic Drive</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com">CSS Drive</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.codingforums.com">Coding Forums</a></li> 
        <li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/">DOM Reference</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>

<div class="column"> 
    <h3>News Related</h3>
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com/">CNN</a></li> <li><a href="http://www.msnbc.com">MSNBC</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li> <li><a href="http://news.bbc.co.uk">BBC News</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>

<div class="column"> 
    <h3>Technology</h3> 
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="http://www.news.com/">News.com</a></li> 
        <li><a href="http://www.slashdot.com">SlashDot</a></li> 
        <li><a href="http://www.digg.com">Digg</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.techcrunch.com">Tech Crunch</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) and [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) like this:

```
$('div.column:eq(1)').after('<br />');
```

That would insert new line ***only after second div***. If you want to insert a new line ***after every second div*** (with respect to previous used div), you need to use [`:nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) instead like this:

```
$('div.column:nth-child(2n)').after('<br />');
```